# How change the font of a title of a slide in python-pptx?

Tags: python, python-pptx

I want to change the font size and font style of the title of the slide. I also want to underline the title. How to do that?

```
from pptx import Presentation

prs = Presentation(ppt_filename)

slide = prs.slides[0]
slide.shapes.title.text = 'New Title'
slide.shapes.title.top = 100
slide.shapes.title.left = 100
slide.shapes.title.height = 200
```

Answer (score 7):

This might be a bit hacky, but it works.

As per the [docs](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), you can access the [`text_frame`](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/shapes.html#pptx.shapes.autoshape.Shape.text_frame) of the [title placeholder shape](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/shapes.html#pptx.shapes.shapetree.SlideShapes.title).
Thanks to that, you can fetch [`Paragraph`](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/text.html#pptx.text.text._Paragraph) objects within this frame with the [`paragraphs`](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/text.html#pptx.text.text.TextFrame.paragraphs) attribute. In the [elements](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/analysis/placeholders/slide-placeholders/placeholders-in-new-slide.html#elements) section here, you can see that the `title` placeholder shape is in the first index (if it exists).

Then we can now get the [`Font`](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/text.html#pptx.text.text._Paragraph.font) being used in the paragraph, and change different attributes of it, as follows:

```
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.util import Pt

prs = Presentation(ppt_filename)

slide = prs.slides[0]
slide.shapes.title.text = 'New Title'
slide.shapes.title.top = 100
slide.shapes.title.left = 100
slide.shapes.title.height = 200

title_para = slide.shapes.title.text_frame.paragraphs[0]

title_para.font.name = "Comic Sans MS"
title_para.font.size = Pt(72)
title_para.font.underline = True
```

---

**Extra References:**

- [`text.Font`](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/text.html#pptx.text.text.Font) - More font attributes you can edit.
- [`util.Pt`](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/util.html#pptx.util.Pt) - Setting the font size.

Comment: That's for the first paragraph, @Diggy. But extending to iterate over all the paragraphs isn't tough. (Yeah, 99% of the time this will complete the task.)

Answer (score 2):

For applying a font style:

```
slide.shapes.title.font.name = 'Calibri'
```

For changing the font size:

```
from pptx.util import Pt
slide.shapes.title.font.size = Pt(20)
```